# Load XML from DB using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to retrieve the XML data from db and bound it to the DropDownList.

XML data in the db field is follows:

```
<Root>
    <ClientName>Jim</ClientName>
    <ClientName>John</ClientName>
    <ClientName>Andrew</ClientName>
</Root>
```

i retrieved the xml data from db field. but, i got next error:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

The following code used to retrieve the xml data from db field. do you have any idea about this problem?

```
var list = from drp in zephyrEntities.UserDefinedFields
           where drp.UDF_ID == udfid
           select drp.LIST_VALUES; // xml field in the db

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XElement xelement = new XElement("UserDefinedList", list);
string str = String.Concat(xelement.Nodes());
doc.LoadXML(str);
XmlNodeList childNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ClientName");
if (childNodes != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.Count; i++)
    {
        XmlNode valueNode = childNodes[i].SelectSingleNode("text()");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you'd say *where* the error occurred. Also, when you've already got the XML in an XElement, why are you then building an XmlDocument from it, and in a strange way?

Comment: You should use either `System.Xml.XmlDocument` or `System.Xml.Linq.XElement`. Not both!

Comment: hi jon, i want to read the data from xelement.so, i load the xelement in the xml document. the error occured at doc.LoadXML(str) line.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear why you store list of entities as one value. Try to normalize your DB model.